# Gorm.Model ID as UUID with Mysql not allowing creation of data

Tags: mysql, go, uuid, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm writing a Go (1.20) backend in Gin (v1.9.1) backend with Gorm (1.25.3), and for my data models I want to use UUID's as the ID. I've been trying to find a way to do this but always end up getting new errors when I try saving a new model into the Mysql database (Mysql Gorm driver V1.5.1) (using PlanetScale).

My model (User) struct looks like this:
`
package models

type User struct {
gorm.Model
ID       uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;default:UUID()"`
Name     string
Email    string
LeagueID string
League   League `gorm:"foreignKey:LeagueID"`
}`

And my CreateUser function looks like this:

`func CreateUser(c *gin.Context) {
newUser := models.User{Name: "John Doe", LeagueID: "id"}

```
result := initializers.DB.Create(&newUser)
if result.Error != nil {
    panic("Failed to create user: " + result.Error.Error())
}

c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newUser)
```

}
`

The error I get from calling this CreateUser function is:

`Scan: unable to scan type int64 into UUID`.

I've tried removing the gorm config on the user ID, like this:

`
package models

type User struct {
gorm.Model
ID       uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey"`
Name     string
Email    string
LeagueID string
League   League `gorm:"foreignKey:LeagueID"`
}`

and having the CreateUser function like this:

`func CreateUser(c *gin.Context) {
newUser := models.User{ID: uuid.New(), Name: "John Doe", LeagueID: "id"}

```
result := initializers.DB.Create(&newUser)
if result.Error != nil {
    panic("Failed to create user: " + result.Error.Error())
}

c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newUser)
```

}
`

But that gives me this error:

`Failed to create user: Error 1265 (01000): target: <repoName>.-.primary: vttablet: Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1 (errno 1265) (sqlstate 01000) (CallerID: bg40zxyib9xefdyfnh2d): Sql: "insert into users(id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at,` name`, email, league_id) values (:vtg1 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg2 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg3 /* VARCHAR */, null, :vtg4 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg5 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg6 /* VARCHAR */)", BindVars: {REDACTED}`

I have tried having the ID key a string, which gives the same error.

I also tried keeping the first id config in, `gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;default:UUID()"`, but still creating the uuid on creation, with `models.User{ID: uuid.New()...`. Then I get this ridiculous error:

`Failed to create user: Error 1366 (HY000): target: <repoName>.-.primary: vttablet: Incorrect integer value: 'f9d6bd3e-f91f-446f-832f-4117731db6cb' for column 'id' at row 1 (errno 1366) (sqlstate HY000) (CallerID: bg40zxyib9xefdyfnh2d): Sql: "insert into users(created_at, updated_at, deleted_at,` name`, email, league_id, id) values (:vtg1 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg2 /* VARCHAR */, null, :vtg3 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg4 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg5 /* VARCHAR */, :vtg6 /* VARCHAR */)", BindVars: {REDACTED}`

which I feel doesn't make any sense.

Sorry for the long post, just wanted to include as much info as I could. I can't seem to find any good help with a google search. ChatGpt is not helping, and the Gorm docs barely mention uuid's. Should I just give up and use integer ids and auto increment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I may have solved this... The problem is that originally, the ID column was set as an integer, and I thought that by changing the ID type, gorms AutoMigrate function would change the column type on the database end. That is not the case, and the database still had the column type as an Int. 

The easiest way to fix this was to simply sign onto the PlanetScale console, and drop the table, then let gorm recreate it with the new id type.